# Ansible - repeat a task while wait_for

Tags: mongodb, ansible

Still learning @Ansible. Trying to automate a MongoDB restore.

I have three servers which run MongoDB. After the restore, the status of the MongoDB servers can be outputted with a shell command (see below).

What I want Ansible to do is to perform a task when the string 'lastHeartbeatMessage' is present after 10 min in the output.

```
- name: Register MongoDB sync status
  shell: mongo --eval "printjson(rs.status())"
  register: mongoReplInfo

- debug: var=mongoReplInfo

- name: Copy rs.status to local log
  local_action: copy content={{ mongoReplInfo }} dest=/tmp/mongoStatus

- name: Copy rs.status to server
  copy: src=/tmp/mongoStatus dest=/tmp/mongoStatus

- name: Check if slave is still syncing
  wait_for: path=/tmp/mongoStatus search_regex=lastHeartbeatMessage

- name: Succesfull sync
  shell: 'run_succesfull_command'
  when: lastHeartbeatMessage is absent after 10 min

- name: Failed sync
  shell: 'run_succesfull_command'
  when: lastHeartbeatMessage is present after 10 min
```

Right now i'm using the wait_for. But the status is only written once to the file, and it is not updated. Which module should I use to repeat the tasks which output the `rs.status` to the server?

Or am I taking this playbook the whole wrong way?

Answer (score 4):

That's a use case for a [do-until loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met) rather than `wait_for`.

The following will register `mongoReplInfo` twice: immediately and after 600 seconds. Then you can check the value for your condition.

```
- name: Register MongoDB sync status
  shell: mongo --eval "printjson(rs.status())"
  register: mongoReplInfo
  until: false
  retries: 2
  delay: 600
```

But you should rather increase the number of retries and check for the condition in `until` parameter, so that the loop exits when the condition is met. Just like in the linked doc chapter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
`    - name: check if still syncing
      action: shell mongo --eval "printjson(rs.status())"
      register: mongoStatus
      until: mongoStatus.stdout.find("lastHeartbeatMessage") != 1
      retries: 50
      delay: 10
      run_once: true` 
Is what I used